# Is this Knapsack-like algorithm correct?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've implemented a simple algorithm for a Knapsack-like problem. I've searched other solutions in similar questions, but I cannot determine if my solution is complete for this specific problem.

The problem:

> Write a function that takes a number a list of numbers. The function should return "true"
>       if number can be calculated using add and subtract operations or "false" otherwise.

Examples:

```
(9, [2,8,5,10]) -> true
(0, [4,3,2,1])  -> true
(0, [])  -> true
(0, [1]) -> false
(1, [1]) -> true
(4, [1,2]-> false
```

From my understanding the algorithm must use all the numbers and should not stop in non-leaf nodes. So this is my code:

```cpp
bool knapSack(int res, const std::vector<int>& v, int index, int cur_add)
{
    bool ret = false;

    if (index < v.size())
    {
        if (v.size() > 0)
        {
            ret = knapSack(res, v, index + 1, cur_add + v[index]);
            if(!ret)
                ret = knapSack(res, v, index + 1, cur_add - v[index]);
        }
    }
    else if(res == cur_add)
        ret = true;

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The result is: " << knapSack(9, { 5,8,10,2 }, 0, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The result is: " << knapSack(0, { 4,3,2,1 }, 0, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The result is: " << knapSack(0, { }, 0, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The result is: " << knapSack(0, { 1 }, 0, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The result is: " << knapSack(1, { 1 }, 0, 0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The result is: " << knapSack(2, { 4,1 }, 0, 0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is this algorithm complete and correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: This might be better-suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). And I'm just curious, would the second `std::move(v)` call always work as expected? If the first `std::move(v)` call puts `v` in an unspecified state, wouldn't the second call try to move an unspecified vector?

Comment: Yes I think you're correct. Maybe it's better to change the second argument to const std::vector<int>& and get rid of move.

Comment: It's correct as far as I can tell. You can probably speed up the algorithm a bit by memorizing the results since your current algorithm could be recomputing some stuff. For example, if all the numbers are the same, the runtime is exponential.

Comment: This seems similar (or equivalent) to [the subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).